# All functions are not running in resume button

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have a JS file which is related to a Wordpress Plugin. It is a Quiz plugin which has a timer.
I have implemented a Pause and resume button which pause the timer and also resume the timer.
But there is some problems with resume.

Resume button code is similar to that of start quiz function but difference is that resume function takes the time of paused timer. But after pressing resume button the problems are:

1. Pause button does not work after pressing resume button.
2. After pressing resume, when time elapses, results page does not show as it does after pressing
   start quiz button.
3. Quiz-summary button does not work.

[Demo URL here](http://weconvex.info/quiz)

There are two similar js files. I am providing which is easy to understand.

[JS FILE](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c52a80a0bd7dce556713)

Actual js file in demo has variable names is difficult to follow. So i provided similar JS file.

when you open js file gists url, follow line no. 99, 1282 and 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly when you click on "Timer resume" error appears in the console issue in line 242, 
h[с].home is undefined reason for this is that when you press the pause function questionStart is assigned to the variable C "undefined"

Use chrome developer tools or firebug to understand where it all went wrong.

And when you choose names for variables is better to choose a name Responding content of the variable rather than simply "a b c" for others and for you when you forget logic will be easier to understand.

Comment: Ok i try to remove some lines.

Comment: this is a plugin js files. I added already similar js file. Try that

Answer (score 0):

> Error is raising due to this line : `C.find("span").val()=C.find("span").textContent();`
>   change it with below code

```
C.find("span").val(C.find("span").textContent());
```

Comment: `textContent()` method is not available for jquery objects. I think you are referring to `text()`. and even `val()` is used for text boxes and thus the jquery code should be `C.find("span").text(C.find("span").text());` but I didn't get what OP is trying to achieve adding the text again to the same element... :/

Comment: Ok. wait i also try this.

Comment: I think the solution is to pass the paused timer time into start() anyhow. There is no need to write any separate resume function. If anybody can suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the time when the pause action is done, use jquery's `data()` method.

#### On pause time

```
C.find("span").data('time',C.find("span").text());
```

#### On resume time

```
//use this value to some variable to resume the time.
var resumeTime = C.find("span").data('time');
```

The above `data()` method is adding a key attribute to your element `C` with a name as "time".

### Updated:

```
var timer = null,
    interval = 1000,
    value = 300; //In seconds, for 5 mins

$("#start").click(function () {
    if (timer !== null) return;
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        value--;
        $("#input").text(Math.floor(value / 60) + ":" + parseInt(value % 60, 10));
    }, interval);
    this.value = "resume";
});

$("#pause").click(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/qHL8Z/180/)

Comment: problem is still same.

Comment: @SudheerPal Can you get the "time" key value attribute in your resume function?